# LazyVerticalGrid Custom Vertical Arrangement

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to write a custom VerticalArragment for a lazyVerticalGrid where:

- items in the first line get a top padding of `10.dp`
- items in the seconds line get a top padding of `20.dp`
- and the rest will get a top padding of `5.dp`

```kotlin
object CustomVerticalArrangement : Arrangement.Vertical {

    override fun Density.arrange(totalSize: Int, sizes: IntArray, outPositions: IntArray) {
        var current = 0
        sizes.forEachIndexed { index, it ->
            when (abs(index / 3) {
                0 -> outPositions[index] = current + 10
                1 -> outPositions[index] = current + 20
                else -> outPositions[index] = current + 5
            }
            current += it
        }
    }
}
```

I pass it over later to my LazyVerticalGrid

```kotlin
LazyVerticalGrid(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
    columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
    contentPadding = PaddingValues(start = 70.dp, end = 70.dp, top = 75.dp, bottom = 40.dp),
    // TODO: consider custom vertical arrangement
    verticalArrangement = CustomVerticalArrangement,
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(10.dp)
) { ... }
```

The code is never called I believe or it’s just that LazyGrid doesn’t consider it and use the default spacing `0.dp`.

the debugger breakpoint never reached By the way
Am I doing something wrong or this is a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is intended! since the LazyGrid composable only uses the spacing field in Arrangement.Vertical which will be 0.dp by default in `LazyGrid.kt`.

```kotlin
val spaceBetweenSlotsDp = if (isVertical) {
            horizontalArrangement?.spacing ?: 0.dp
        } else {
            verticalArrangement?.spacing ?: 0.dp
        }
```